# include sql result to php mail

Tags: php, sql, email, foreach

I would like to ask if what is missing in my script for sending mail, my query is fine and it shows results and I'd like to ask for help on how to include those query result into the message that I will send out. I'd really appreciate it if you could give me an advice where to start. thanks.

```
    <?php

    $cfg = array(

        'display' => 'gw@mail.com',
        'address' => 'support@mail.com',
        'subject' => 'TEST '
            . date("m/d/t h:i:s A", strtotime('TODAY')) . ' hits',

        'queries' => array(
            "SELECT inbox.src AS 'From Mobile Number', outbox.dst AS 'To Mobile Number', outbox.stamp AS 'Timestamp', inbox.data AS 'Message', outbox.status AS 'Status' FROM mega.outbox LEFT JOIN mega.inbox ON outbox.pid=inbox.pid WHERE outbox.sid=156 && inbox.sid=156 && stamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR",

        ),
    );

    include "/var/xrelay/mysql.php";
    $sql = new database();

    $msg = '';
    foreach( $cfg['queries'] as $i ) {
       $tmp = $sql->read($i, true);
       if (!empty($tmp)) {
          foreach($tmp[0] as $k => $v) $msg .= "$k: $v\r\n";
       }
    }

    foreach( preg_split( '/[\s,]+/', $cfg['address'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $i ) {
       $sql->write("INSERT INTO mega.emails (sender,recipient,subject,message,stamp) VALUES "
       . "('{$cfg['display']}','$i','{$cfg['subject']}','".$sql->escape($msg)."', NOW());");
    }

    ?>
```

---

Is there any way to improve this more? this mailer supposed to send mail to a recipient every 3hours if there are any activity from the db. it will retrieve data last 3 hours ago and put the result as message.

> 

```
include "/var/xrelay/mysql.php";
$sql = new database('sql://gateway:xrelay@00.000.000.000/test');
$cfg = array(

   'display' => 'gw@mail.com',
   'address' => 'g@mail.com',
   'subject' => 'MAIL HITS ' . date("m/d/y h:i:s A", strtotime("NOW")) . ' hits',

   );

//define('DEBUG',true);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT outbox.dst, DATE_FORMAT(outbox.stamp,'%b-%d-%Y %h:%i %p')AS 'Stamp', outbox.status FROM mega.outbox LEFT JOIN mega.inbox ON outbox.pid=inbox.pid WHERE outbox.sid=156 && inbox.sid=156 && outbox.stamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR");
$msg='|  Mobile#      |         Timestamp          |  Status  |\r\n';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
   $msg .= "| ". $row['dst'] ." | ". $row['Stamp'] ." | ". $row['status'] ." |\r\n";
  }
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $msg;
if($num_rows != 0){
foreach( preg_split( '/[\s,]+/', $cfg['address'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $i ) {
   $sql->write("INSERT INTO mega.emails (sender,recipient,subject,message,stamp) VALUES " . "('{$cfg['display']}','$i','{$cfg['subject']}','". $msg ."', NOW());");
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the results you should create a string that you would append to the body of the e-mail. You can use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for this purpose.

If you are looking for a way to send the actual e-mail, the [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function is explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).